# Go back from opened PDF to app

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I'm working in an IOS app that displays a webpage. I'm using UIWebView and it works well. In the webpage there are links to PDF documents. 
The problem is, when the PDF opens, there's no way to go back, only closing and open again the app.
Is there a way to open PDF in another app or only to download?
I'm working with Swift 2.2.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This will help getting useful answers

Answer (score 0):

Add a toolbar for the webview and add some back and forward navigation buttons to enable you to navigate the web pages. A great example exists on hackingwithswift.com. Hope this helps.

Comment: But is there a way the toolbar displays only when pdf opens?

Comment: Can make the toolbar appear and disappear on swipe.